# Can you put a function inside of another function in c++?

Tags: c++, function

Say I have two functions, and one calls the other to work.

```
void friendList::addFriend(string userNameIn) 
{
    if(friendList::isFriend(userNameIn))
        //add friend
}

bool friendList::isFriend(string name)
{
    //check if user name exists
}
```

Is this allowed? I am getting errors for:
`In member function 'void User::addFriend(std::string)':
and error: cannot call member function 'bool friendList::isFriend(std::string)' without object`

Is it because the functions aren't completely filled out yet?

Comment: Is `friendList` a type?  Are these functions (`addFriend()` and `isFriend()`) member functions of that type?  The answer to this question will determine what the _correct_ answer to your question is.

Comment: Is the code you pasted actually the real code? In the code you have `friendList::addFriend` but you refer to `User::addFriend` below. If `addFriend()` is really in `User` then you need a `friendList` object to call `isFriend` on.

Comment: Yes friendList is a type I created, and addFriend and isFriend are both functions of friendList. I am trying to define them currently. addFriend is in both User and friendList

Comment: Post your class declaration, or atleast the relevant parts

Comment: The error you are getting is about the code in `User::addFriend`, which you haven't shown here. Please post the declaration of the `User` and `friendList` classes, and the body of `User::addFriend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, functions can of course call other functions in C++.

Doing so is **not a case of functions being put inside other functions**: your question title is misleading.

It looks as if `addFriend` might be a static member function, and as such it has no object, whereas `isFriend` is a non-static member function.  When a static member function of a class calls a non-static member function, it must supply an object:

```
class someclass {
// ...
   static void static_member();
   void nonstatic_member();
};

void some_class::static_member()
{
  nonstatic_member(); // error
  some_instance.nonstatic_member(); // okay
}

void some_class::nonstatic_member()
{
}
```

`static_member` cannot call `nonstatic_member`, but it can invoke `nonstatic_member` on an object. It will work provided that `some_instance` is suitably defined somewhere as an instance of `some_class`.

Comment: @robertjskelton: you don't need an object as you are inside of one. Simple change `if(friendList::isFriend(userNameIn))` to `if(isFriend(userNameIn))` and object you currently work with will be used. Read about `this` object

Comment: I suspect you could benefit from an intensive C++ tutorial, as well as going through a good book.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error:

> cannot call member function [...] without object

Suggests to me that you are trying to call a non-`static` member function *directly*, rather than through an object.  For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int DoIt() {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo::DoIt();
}
```

If that's what you're trying to do, you can't.  Non-`static` member functions need to be called through an object:

```
int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.DoIt();
}
```

If you *must* refrain from calling through an object, then you need to make the member function `static`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  static int DoIt() {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo::DoIt(); // OK
}
```

But then, `DoIt` won't be able to call other non-`static` member functions.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the 'this' pointer.  `this->isFriend(userNameIn)`

Comment: There's already an implicit `this` in there. His code is equivalent to `this->friendList::isFriend(userNameIn)`.

Comment: sure you're right, Daniel Frey articulated what I meant much better.  You can use this or not it's up to you all I was saying is you need to call it on an object instead as if it were a static function.

Comment: On the plus side, explicitly saying `this->` would cause compilation to fail with a more descriptive error if `addFriend` is static (or in another class).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Exactly.  And the compiler will tell you as much if you try to use it in a static function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't believe I said they did but thanks for the -1.